# Azure Front Door Managed Identify to Read Storage Blob -Authorization Error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-managed-identity, azure-front-door

I am trying to use Managed Identity at the Azure Front Door to access (read) Azure Storage Blob. As prerequisite, I assigned "Storage Blob Data Reader" RBAC to the managed identity in Storage Account IAM but I am consistently getting authorization error. It appears that Front Door is sending request as Anonymous!

My expectation is, I shouldn't have to pass Authorization header in the request since managed identity is used. I am able to connect to Azure Key Vault using managed identity of front door but same is not working on storage account!

There is no network restriction on storage account. It is set to Enabled from all networks (for the purpose of POC).

For the sake of testing, I made the blob access level to Blob (anonymous access) and I was able to read the blob using front door endpoint but I can't make the blob public for security reason.

Any recommendation how to access private blobs from Azure Front Door securely?

Answer (score 1):

> I made the blob access level to Blob (anonymous access) and I was able to read the blob using front door endpoint, but I can't make the blob public for security reason.

***Note*** that Managed Identity is not integrated between AFD and storage yet. AFD Premium supports Private Link, which can be used to access storage privately.

To connect to Azure Key Vault using managed identity of front door you can make use of this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/managed-identity?tabs=system-assigned)

Using Azure front door Premium created, create private link service and WAF policy and select custom origin type and enable private link service like below:

[image]

[image]

Created a private endpoint in Azure storage account to access securely and select the pending private endpoint request from Azure Front Door Premium then select Approve like below:

[image]

[image]

Once the Azure front door created with host name storage account blob will access private blobs securely:

[image]

***References***:

[Connect Azure Front Door Premium to a storage account origin with Private Link - Azure Private Link | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-enable-private-link-storage-account)

[Secure your Origin with Private Link in Azure Front Door Premium | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/private-link)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to address my question. I did try the AFD Premium tier and configured the private endpoint. It does allow access to storage over private network but it does not address my concern on Authentication. Network control can't satisfy Authentication requirement. My attempt to use SAS key was not good. Once instance, AFD showed the entire url including SAS key to browser as there was issue with the rule. Managed Identity would be the solution but as you mentioned it is not available at this time. I would wait for Managed Identity support for storage account.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions presented [here](https://mikestephenson.me/2023/05/19/using-a-sas-token-from-frontdoor-to-storage/#post/0) by Mike Stephenson looks the one you were searching for. Storage Account is preserved private, the query string on the client doesn't expose any query parameter. As a plus, it requires only a Frontdoor Standard (30$ Month), against Frontdoor Premium with Private Link enabled (300+ $/month).

Meanwhile I hope that Microsoft will put inside the pipeline the development of native integration with System Assigned Managed Identity, to authenticate against storage account.

Comment: @Giulio-Fronterotta- Thanks for sharing the post by mikestephenson. Mike indeed did a good job explaining pros and cons. As you can imagine, you will have many containers and paths would be different along with SAS tokens. Url Rewrite rule has to be smart to take care of the correct route. Any mistake in the url rewrite rule may result in entire url (including SAS token) shown in the response. Thta's exactly what happened to me! I would call SAS token use a band-aid solution and I would wait for Microsoft to integrate managed identity on AFD to access storage account.